# The chrome.runtime message is not being sent in google chrome extension

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

I have my utility class, where I calculate how many text analysis a user made. Once a user performs text analysis, I send a message to my popup.js UI, where I need to update the corresponding number.

Here is my function in my business_logic.js file:

```
performTextChecking(text) {
const self = this; // Save a reference to 'this' for use inside the callback function

return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
  self.retrieveTextCheckings((textCheckings) => {
    self.textCheckings = textCheckings;

    if (self.hasSubscription || self.textCheckings < self.monthlyLimit) {
      // Perform the text checking
      self.textCheckings++;
      console.log('textCheckings in performTextChecking:', self.textCheckings);
      // Send message to popup.js to update the UI
      chrome.runtime.sendMessage({ action: 'updateCredits', credits: self.textCheckings });
      // Update the stored text checkings count in local storage
      chrome.storage.local.set({ textCheckings: self.textCheckings }, () => {
        chrome.storage.local.get('textCheckings', (result) => {
          console.log('textCheckings in performTextChecking (after set):', result.textCheckings);
        });

        // Send the text to the server and return the result
        self.sendTextToServer(text)
          .then(resultText => {
            resolve(resultText);
          })
          .catch(error => {
            console.error('Text checking failed:', error);
            resolve(null);
          });
      });
    } else {
    
      // Set textCheckings for test purposes
      self.textCheckings = 0;
      chrome.storage.local.set({ textCheckings: self.textCheckings }, () => {
        resolve(null);
      });

      // Send message to popup.js to update the UI
      chrome.runtime.sendMessage({ action: 'updateCredits', credits: self.textCheckings });

      // Prompt the user to subscribe
      self.showSubscriptionPopup();

    }
  });
});
```

}

So I send `chrome.runtime.sendMessage({ action: 'updateCredits', credits: self.textCheckings });` to my UI to update it accordingly.

In my popup.js file I have the following listener:

```
    // Listen for messages from the background script
chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(function(request, sender, sendResponse) {
  if (request.action === 'updateCredits') {
    const creditsCountElement = document.getElementById('creditsCount');
    console.log('creditsCountElement in popup.js:', request.credits);
    creditsCountElement.textContent = request.credits;
  }
});
```

However, my UI is not being updated. Moreover, I don't see that my listener in popup.js is not being called at all. I think that the message is not being sent properly from business_logic.js. What can I resolve that?

Here is my manifest file:

```
    {
  ....
  "browser_action": {
    "default_popup": "popup/popup.html"
  },
  "permissions": [
    "http://*/",
    "https://*/",
    "contextMenus",
    "activeTab",
    "browser_action",
    "storage"
  ],
  "icons": {
    "16": "images/logo.png",
    "48": "images/logo.png",
    "128": "images/logo.png"
  },
  "background": {
    "scripts": ["background.js", "server/business_logic.js"]
  },
  "content_scripts": [
    {
      "matches": ["<all_urls>", "https://docs.google.com/*", "https://www.linkedin.com/*"],
      "js": ["bottom_button/bottom_button.js", "server/business_logic.js"]
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: How do you run/load business_logic.js?

Comment: @wOxxOm I added my manifest file to the question

Comment: You load this script both as a background script and a content script, but these contexts are very different, so I guess you might be looking at [the wrong one](/q/38913799).

Answer (score -1):

One solution I can suggest about the listener popup.js *(since they aren't being called assuming that the if statement was declared false)* is to replace the operator **===** with **.equals()** to prevent the value of request.action to be strict. Seeing that request can be a potential object, it's possible that you are evaluating the value request.action equals to the String as exact in the memory.

Otherwise, that's one potential problem that may affect your popup.js function properly.

The code can be replaced as followed:

```
chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(function(request, sender, sendResponse) {
  if (request.action.equals('updateCredits')) {
    const creditsCountElement = document.getElementById('creditsCount');
    console.log('creditsCountElement in popup.js:', request.credits);
    creditsCountElement.textContent = request.credits;
  }
});
```

Comment: Thank you, but replacing it to equals didn't work.